# How to input :binary_id in iex command line?

Tags: elixir, ecto, elixir-iex

I am writing an application in Elixir with Postgres as the data store. In Ecto, I defined this entity:

```
defmodule MyModule.User do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  @primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
  end

  @fields ~w(email)

  def changeset(data, params \\ %{}) do
    data
    |> cast(params, @fields)
    |> validate_required([:email])
    |> validate_length(:email, max: 128)
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
  end
end
```

Then, I can save a record in the db in `iex`-terminal by typing:

```
iex> user1 = MyModule.User.changeset(%MyModule.User{}, %{email: "foo@bar.com"})
iex> MyModule.Repo.insert!(user1)
```

Everything runs ok and the record gets saved. But when I try to retrieve it with `Repo.get()`:

```
iex> MyModule.Repo.get(MyModule.User, 0)
```

I get this error:

```
** (Ecto.Query.CastError) deps/ecto/lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:320:
value `0` in `where` cannot be cast to type :binary_id in query:

from u in ScorecardBackend.User,
  where: u.id == ^0,
  select: u

  (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1755: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
  (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1325: Enum."-map_reduce/3-lists^mapfoldl/2-0-"/3
```

My question: Is there a way to type `:binary_id` literals in the `iex`-command line? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `binary_id` field is represented as a String in Elixir, so you need to pass a String to `Repo.get` containing the the `binary_id`, for example:

```
MyModule.Repo.get(MyModule.User, "0e31998f-503f-4218-a801-c8bb7ff9498b")
```

The exact length and format of a `binary_id` field depends on the database. In PostgreSQL, it's a UUID and the default one auto generated is a random UUID. You can see what ID was generated by fetching all the records:

```
MyModule.Repo.all(MyModule.User)
```